# Flutter - How do I check if a variable exists?

Tags: if-statement, flutter, dart, widget

I have two constructors in **new_activity_config.dart**.

```
  NewActivityConfig(this.activityType, {Key key, this.activity}) : super(key: key);
  NewActivityConfig.fromNewActivityConfig(this.activity, {Key key, this.activityType}) : super(key: key);
```

One takes in an **activityType**: this.name, this.image

The other takes in an **activity**: this.name, this.image, this.status, this.scheduledStart, this.mapped, this.description, this.statistics, this.completionDate, this.duration

When navigating from the Pick Activity screen, it will call the **NewActivityConfig()** constructor - because it is showing an empty Config page for the user to input values

When selecting an already created activity, it will call the **NewActivityConfig.fromNewActivityConfig()**, passing in variables that had been previously input to fill the fields.

In my TextField hintText, I would like to display the user's input description if the **description** variable exists. However, if the first constructor is called (not passing in any user's previous values) and getDescription() cannot be called because it hasn't been passed in - and receive the error: `The method getDescription() was called on null`.

How can I check if this exists without running into null errors?

```
final description = TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText:(widget.activity.getDescription() != null ? widget.activity.getDescription() : 'Enter an activity description'),
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if `activity` itself is null or not before you can access its attributes or behaviors.
Try this:

```
   final description = TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText:(widget.activity != null ? widget.activity.getDescription() : 'Enter an activity description'),
      )
    );
```